# Using handlebars to fill select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars js to try and populate a select box, but it never puts the json objects in to the box.

My JSON:

```
{
    "d": [{
        "__type": "Admin_Webhook+Color",
        "ColorID": 1,
        "ColorName": "Red"
    }, {
        "__type": "Admin_Webhook+Color",
        "ColorID": 2,
        "ColorName": "Yellow"
    }, {
        "__type": "Admin_Webhook+Color",
        "ColorID": 3,
        "ColorName": "Blue"
    }]
}
```

My HB Template:

```
<div class="option-static">
    <div>Colors:</div>
    <select size="10">
        <option value="0">-Add New Color-</option>
        {{#each d}}
        <option value="{{ColorID}}">{{ColorName}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" onclick="RemoveColor()" value="Remove Color" />
</div>
```

My Append:

```
function BindColorList() {
    console.log("Page bound");
    var source = $("#HB-ColorTemplate").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template();
    $("#ColorTemp").append(html);
}
```

It creates the html including the select box with the -Add New Color- but does nothing with the json.

Comment: You need to pass your data to your template: `var html = template(data);`

Comment: @76484 Wow, I can't believe I looked right over that. Thank you so much, was wracking my brain trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.